# Delete an item using an OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview, android-alertdialog

I want to delete an item from the ListView using an OnItemLongClickListener.
This is my code to make an AlertDialog appear when I OnLongClick an item.
I also need to now what code to use when I delete an Item

```
public class DeleteItem extends Activity {

 ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(DeleteItem.this);
                alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
                alert.setCancelable(false);
                alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Here I need the delete code
                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });


                return false;

            }
        });

       }
    }
```

Comment: what kind of adapter do you have

Comment: Something along the lines of 1) Remove the item from the array you are using to populate the list 2) call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I have an ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayAdapter has the method `remove(int index)`:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int position, long arg3) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(DeleteItem.this);
            alert.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ArrayAdapter yourArrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) arg0.getAdapter();
                    yourArrayAdapter.remove(position);
                    yourArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });


            return false;

        }
    });
```

Adjust the cast with the generic type of your adapter. It works only if you provide a Collection of elements to the adapter. If you provided an Array it will throw an exception